# Как удалить строку в таблице c помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript

Как удалить строку в таблице c помощью javascript?
Сделала так, чтобы заполняемые поля добавлялись в таблицу. 
Не могу сделать так, чтобы можно было выборочно удалять строки из таблицы.
Нашла в инете отличный пример с отдельной ячейкой, но не могу применить к себе, у меня не работает. 
Помогите соединить с моим кодом - https://jsfiddle.net/d2vyecu6/1

Мой код:

```js
var d = document;

var name;
var field;
var posada;

function addRow()
{
    // Считываем значения с формы
    name = d.getElementById('name').value;
    field = d.getElementById('field').value;
    posada = d.getElementById('posada').value;

    // Находим нужную таблицу
    var tbody = d.getElementById('tab1').getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0];

    // Создаем строку таблицы и добавляем ее
    var row = d.createElement("TR");
    tbody.appendChild(row);

    // Создаем ячейки в вышесозданной строке
    // и добавляем тх
    var td1 = d.createElement("TD");
    var td2 = d.createElement("TD");
    var td3 = d.createElement("TD");
   

    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    // row.appendChild(td3); сюда добавить поле, указав пордок ячейки row.appendChild(td3); 


    // Наполняем ячейки
    td1.innerHTML = name;
    td2.innerHTML = field;
    td3.innerHTML = posada;
    

    // сюда добавить поле вида:  td4.innerHTML = posada;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Привет мир!</title>
    
</head>
<body>

    <table id="tab1" class="sortable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ФИО</th>
                <th>Должность</th>
                <th>Field</th>
                <th>Удалить</th>
                <!-- <th>Field</th>
                Добавить заголовок в таблицу
                -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <form action="" id="add_persons" method="post" onsubmit="addRow();return false;">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Добавить сотрудника</legend>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Фамилия</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="12" tabindex="1" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="field">Инициалы</label>
                    <input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li>
                <!-- Добавить поле для вывода -->
                <!-- <li>
                    <label for="field">Инициалы</label>
                    <input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li> -->
                <li>
                    <label for="posada">Должность</label>
                    <input type="text" name="posada" id="posada" value="" size="12" tabindex="3" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="subm">Действия</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="subm" class="submit" value="Добавить" tabindex="4" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    <script src="1.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>

        <!-- Добавить поле для вывода -->
                <!-- <li>
                    <label for="field">Инициалы</label>
                    <input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li> -->
```

Comment: А где пример вашей функции удаления строчки?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Добавляете td4. И вешаете либо на всю ячейку либо на элемент внутни него (кнопку допустим):

```
td4.addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.closest('tr').remove()
});
```

Вашу функционал на js чуть короче можно сделать:

```
function addRow()
{    
    let d = document
    let name = d.getElementById('name').value
    let field = d.getElementById('field').value
    let posada = d.getElementById('posada').value
    let tbody = d.querySelector('#tab1 tbody')    
    tbody.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${field}</td><td>${posada}</td> 
    <td><button onclick="this.closest('tr').remove()">Удалить</button></td></tr>`    
}
```

```js
function addRow()
{    
    let d = document
    let name = d.getElementById('name').value
    let field = d.getElementById('field').value
    let posada = d.getElementById('posada').value        
    let tbody = d.querySelector('#tab1 tbody')    
    tbody.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${field}</td><td>${posada}</td><td><button onclick="this.closest('tr').remove()">Удалить</button></td></tr>`    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Привет мир!</title>
    
</head>
<body>

    <table id="tab1" class="sortable" style="border:solid 1px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ФИО</th>
                <th>Должность</th>
                <th>Field</th>
                <th>Удалить</th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <form action="" id="add_persons" method="post" onsubmit="addRow();return false;">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Добавить сотрудника</legend>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Фамилия</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="12" tabindex="1" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="field">Инициалы</label>
                    <input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li>
                <!-- Добавить поле для вывода -->
                <!-- <li>
                    <label for="field">Инициалы</label>
                    <input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li> -->
                <li>
                    <label for="posada">Должность</label>
                    <input type="text" name="posada" id="posada" value="" size="12" tabindex="3" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="subm">Действия</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="subm" class="submit" value="Добавить" tabindex="4" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    <script src="1.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>

        <!-- Добавить поле для вывода -->
                <!-- <li>
                    <label for="field">Инициалы</label>
                    <input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, если делать быстро на коленках

```js
var d = document;

var name;
var field;
var posada;

function addRow()
{
    // Считываем значения с формы
    name = d.getElementById('name').value;
    field = d.getElementById('field').value;
    posada = d.getElementById('posada').value;

    // Находим нужную таблицу
    var tbody = d.getElementById('tab1').getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0];

    // Создаем строку таблицы и добавляем ее
    var row = d.createElement("TR");
    tbody.appendChild(row);

    // Создаем ячейки в вышесозданной строке
    // и добавляем тх
    var td1 = d.createElement("TD");
    var td2 = d.createElement("TD");
    var td3 = d.createElement("TD");
    var td4 = d.createElement("TD");
   
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    row.appendChild(td3);
    row.appendChild(td4);    


    // Наполняем ячейки
    td1.innerHTML = name;
    td2.innerHTML = field;
    td3.innerHTML = posada;
    td4.innerHTML = "X";
    
    td4.addEventListener("click", function(e){
      this.parentElement.parentElement.deleteRow(this.parentElement.rowIndex - 1)
    });

    

    // сюда добавить поле вида:  td4.innerHTML = posada;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Привет мир!</title>
    
</head>
<body>

    <table id="tab1" class="sortable" style="border:solid 1px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ФИО</th>
                <th>Должность</th>
                <th>Field</th>
                <th>Удалить</th>                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <form action="" id="add_persons" method="post" onsubmit="addRow();return false;">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Добавить сотрудника</legend>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="name">Фамилия</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="12" tabindex="1" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="field">Инициалы</label>
                    <input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li>
                <!-- Добавить поле для вывода -->
                <!-- <li>
                    <label for="field">Инициалы</label>
                    <input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li> -->
                <li>
                    <label for="posada">Должность</label>
                    <input type="text" name="posada" id="posada" value="" size="12" tabindex="3" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="subm">Действия</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="subm" class="submit" value="Добавить" tabindex="4" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        </form>
    <script src="1.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>

        <!-- Добавить поле для вывода -->
                <!-- <li>
                    <label for="field">Инициалы</label>
                    <input type="text" name="field" id="field" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
                </li> -->
```